# ¿Porque no entra en el switch y porque no coge el parametro inicial?

Tags: php

Estoy haciedno un juego, son 3 dados y segun salga un numero pues obtienes un premio u otro. Mi problema es que no coge los créditos iniciales como parámetros, ni entra al swing.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>5 magico </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $creditos = 100;
        function partida(&$creditos) {
             if ($creditos > 9) {
                $creditos = $_POST['creditos'];
                $creditos -= 10;
                $fichas =0;
                $num1 = random_int(0, 9);
                $num2 = random_int(0, 9);
                $num3 = random_int(0, 9);
                $resultado = array($num1, $num2, $num3);
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) {
                    switch ($resultado[$i]) {
                        case 2:
                            $fichas += 25;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $fichas += 100;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            $fichas += 5;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    $comentario = "has conseguidos" +$fichas + "de premio";
                    $creditos += $fichas;
                }
            } else {
                $comentario = "no hay suficientes creditos";
            }

            return array($creditos, $num1, $num2, $num3,$comentario);
        }
        $resultado = partida($creditos);
        $creditos = $resultado[0];
        $num1 = $resultado[1];
        $num2 = $resultado[2];
        $num3 = $resultado[3];
        ?>
        <p>Tienes <?php echo $creditos; ?>  creditos</p>
        <form name="InferfazPartida" method="post">
            <p>Patida del 5 magico</p>
            <br/>
            <input type="hidden" name="creditos" value="<?php echo $creditos; ?>" />
            <br/>
            <label for="num1">Dado 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" readonly value="<?php echo $num1; ?>"  />

            <label for="num2">Dado 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" readonly value="<?php echo $num2; ?>"  />

            <label for="num1">Dado 3</label>
            <input type="text" name="num3" id="num3" readonly value="<?php echo $num3; ?>"  />

            <input type="submit" value="jugar"/>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, revisé el código que compartiste y encontré dos elementos importantes, uno es que la concatenación del string "Comentarios" la debes hacer con `.` no con `+`, de igual forma pude evidenciar que si se esta llamando el Switch dadas las condiciones que tienes dispuestas.

Te comparto el código que estructuré conforme a tu ejemplo y parece estar funcionando correctamente:

```
$creditos = 100;
    function partida(&$creditos) {
         if ($creditos > 9) {
            //$creditos = $_POST['creditos'];
            $creditos -= 10;
            $fichas =0;
            $num1 = random_int(0, 9);
            $num2 = random_int(0, 9);
            $num3 = random_int(0, 9);
            $resultado = array($num1, $num2, $num3);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) {
                switch ($resultado[$i]) {
                    case 2:
                        $fichas += 25;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $fichas += 100;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $fichas += 5;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
             $comentario = "has conseguidos " .$fichas. " de premio";
                $creditos += $fichas;
        } else {
            $comentario = "no hay suficientes creditos";
        }

        return array($creditos, $num1, $num2, $num3,$comentario);
    }
    $resultado = partida($creditos);
    $creditos = $resultado[0];


    $num1 = $resultado[1];
    $num2 = $resultado[2];
    $num3 = $resultado[3];
    $comentario = $resultado[4];



    echo "Creditos ".$creditos." - Num1 ".$num1. " -Num2 ".$num2." -Num3 ".$num3." Comentario: ".$comentario;
```

Estas reinicializando la variable "Creditos" con lo que encuentra en $_POST["creditos"]; entonces para qué se la envías a la función? Supongo que puede ser lo que este causandote problemas con lo que mencionas con el valor inicial de los créditos. En el código que te compartí, esta comentada esa línea y parece funcionar correctamente, ya que el output evidencia el uso de 10 créditos por partida y otorga fichas según haya ganado o no el participante.
Además de ello, la variable de "Comentarios" debe llenarse una vez que termine el `for` de manera que la variable `fichas` termine de sumar todas las fichas obtenidas según los 3 intentos que se puede tener para ganar créditos.

Espero te sirva! :) Saludos

Comment: Si te das cuenta no parte de 100 creditos, laverdad es que le paso $post porque quiero que en el htlm me muestre los creditos que tengo y si la pongo ne otro sitiio no sae